# Trying to implement table view and getting Thread 1: signal SIGABRT error?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, tableview, sigabrt

I have been trying to implement a simple table view in Xcode. However I have run into this error:

[UIView tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fd23bc76bc0

I searched for an answer online, and basically all I could find out was that I'm trying to send that method something that does not exist. If someone could please explain what exactly is going on here, why it is going, and how I might fix it, I would be grateful. Here is the code:

In ViewController.h :

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController <UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource>
{
}

@end
```

In ViewController.m :

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController
{
    NSArray *recipes;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad {

    [super viewDidLoad];

    recipes = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Eggs", @"Bacon", @"Ham", @"Steak", @"Bread", @"Lettuce", @"Tomatoes", @"Carrots", @"Milk", @"Pizza", @"Chicken", @"Soup", @"Cheese", nil];
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {

    return [recipes count];

}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *simpleTableID = @"SimpleTableCell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableID];

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:simpleTableID];
    }

    cell.textLabel.text = [recipes objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    return cell;

}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@end
```

If you need anymore information, I'd be happy to get it to you. Thanks.

Comment: Your heading the right direction. The message being sent isn't recognized. How could that be? You think you are setting ViewController to be the delegate of the UITableView, but you must be setting it to something other than an instance of ViewController; hence the unrecognized selector crash.

Comment: Very likely the table datasource is setup in storyboard, pointing to something other than the view controller.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you have dragged the delegate property of the table view onto a UIView instead of the UiViewController.

In the storyboard make sure you drag the delegate property to the controller (yellow circle at the top of the view).

Comment: It all makes perfect sense now. I did drag the delegate incorrectly.